# Skype blocks the audio of other applications during call with headphones

Tags: audio, skype, headphones

I am trying to play a sound and talk on Skype at the same time. The problem is that Skype seems to be blocking the line, so when I am on Skype talking to someone and playing a game, the sounds from the game doesn't come at my phones, instead they are played from my notebook speakers... When the call is over the sound come back to my headphones.

Is there a configuration to change it? I want to hear both peoples voice and game sounds on the same device (on my phones)...

**Repro steps**:

1. Have a headphones plugged
2. Configure Skype to use the headphones
3. Start a music
4. Make a call

**Result**: The music will be played on another device and skype will take the primary device for the call blocking other sounds on this device.

**Expected result**: Both sounds to come from the same device.

My sound configurations are like this

[image: config]

I cannot set the default device as `Independent Dual Headphones`, the system doesn't allow me. The other option is `Speakers and Dual Headphones`. I think this device is a problem, I think I need to somehow disable the speakers or find a way to run an application in a way it will use the `Independent Dual Headphones` instead. What can I do?

Related:

- [Skype blocks other sound sources in Win7](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows/Skype-blocks-other-sound-sources-in-Win7/td-p/90)
- [Skype blocks all sound sources in Win7](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows/Skype-blocks-all-sound-sources-in-Win7/td-p/323408)

Comment: Not just in a call, whenever Skype plays a sound it changes the output of other sounds as well.\

Comment: I have noticed that skype turns my other sounds lower, but not that it disables them or sends them through another output. You could maybe try to turn your speakers off in `compmgmt.msc`, under the device manager tab.

Comment: Have you checked the communications tab on that Sound window of Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To play all sound on one device do the following:

```
Open Skype preferences under Tools -> Options -> Audio settings
Select "Speakers/Headphones" as Speakers.
Select "Use selected speaker" as Ringing.
Uncheck "Automatically adjust speaker settings" for Speakers.
```

More details are here:

http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows/Does-your-music-alert-sounds-play-through-speakers-when-you-do-a/td-p/484041

Comment: this option is missing in the latest skype.

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved, tried best answer above to uncheck in Skype, still a problem lowered VLC Media Player volume merely for Skyping. Found success then for Windows 10 anyway, go to Control Panel, click big green 'Hardware & Sound', under Sound click 'Manage audio devices', click 'Communications', check 'Do nothing' for the "When Windows detects communications activity:" to thus uncheck any volume reduction.

Answer (score 1):

Deactivate "independent dual headphones"

This makes your standard sound system control of device you have.

Answer (score 0):

One cannot stream an mp3 music file when using Skype so the other person in the call could listen to it, because Skype doesn’t allow extra sound channels to interfere with the audio call.

To solve this problem, you require a third-party product that integrates with Skype.

One such products is [PrettyMay](http://www.prettymay.net/callrecorder/index.htm), whose free Basic version does :

> Play recorded calls/voicemails/audio files (.mp3 or .wav format) in
>   conversations.

But it also does other functions, such as recording calls.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
Try: 
Tools -> audio settings ->

speakers settings as 'speakers and headphones', then uncheck 'automatically adjust speaker settings'
ringing settings as '(communication/ dual / whatever type) headphones'

Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to play a game and Skype at the same time and this sound splitting was so annoying. Here is how the issue is solved on HP computers or other using SRS audio setting.

1. Normally from the taskbar next to the clock double-click the SRS software to open the Control Panel.
2. At Advanced settings there is a multistreaming option available. If you disable it then all output goes either through the speakers or the headphones when you plug them in.
3. For those who do not use SRS, you may try to disable the headphones as a device from Windows "sound" option at the playback devices.

Answer (score -1):

I had to hit the Set Default button (the one on the menu in the picture in this fix) to finally get my sound back. Nothing else worked.